# use of graphics stock icon (spoon,fork,skull head) for logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, icon, copyright, stock-images

I am a new graphics designer I want to  use skull head, spoon icon, fork, etc in my logo from free stock but I don't know how to avoid copyright issue

Comment: If you wish to "avoid copyright issues" *never* use stock images. And **most**, if not all, stock image sites expressly forbid use in a logo unless all rights have been purchased.

Comment: If the shape is so innocuous and plain that you feel it's merely a nondescript "icon" then simply draw your own. A "spoon" or "fork" could simply fall into that area. A "skull" would depend a great deal upon the artwork itself. In many cases, a "skull" may be too unique to be classified as a general "shape".

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: don't use other's work in any logo you design - yours or a client's.

That will avoid any copyright issue.

However, also bear in mind that a "derivative' work, at least here in the US (and I believe in UK & EU, but others will have to verify) doesn't *have* to start with a literal copy: if you copy the *design intent*, the *idea*, the *visual concept*, and execute it yourself, you can still be at legal risk.

Put it another way away from the legal nonsense - why would you ***want*** to use someone else's work for your logo as a designer anyway?